# HealthCheckUI (AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) Unexpected Character 'H' error

Tags: asp.net-core, health-check

I'm having an issue with the AspNetCore HealthCheckUI.

I followed this example:
https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#healthcheckui

My UI is up and running and my services are up and running with a healthcheck that just returns a string "Healthy".  And I think that's the root cause of the issue.

It looks like the UI is showing a "false" error because it's expecting JSON and seeing a string.  And so it's throwing an "Unexpected character 'H'" error while parsing the response.

Is there a way to stop the healthcheckui from expecting json?

Is there a way have this AspNetCore HealthChecksUI package work with a Healthcheck that doesn't return JSON?

[image]

Comment: Hi, how is your code like? Here is a sample you could follow:https://sahansera.dev/aspdotnet-core-health-checks/

Comment: Thank you @Rena.  I will go through your website and see if I can find anything.  I also updated my question, my code looks exactly like this example: https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks#healthcheckui

Comment: @Rena i pulled down the code from your website and unfortunately they are using JSON responses also

Comment: but thanks for finding that article, let me know if you find any more :)

Comment: @Rena i will definitely be putting a bounty on this tomorrow just in case you still want to help me :)  thank youuuu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the closest thing I could find to an answer, which is basically change all my healthchecks to json :(

https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/issues/440

Comment: hmm..i'm still getting the issue despite specifying the return as json

Comment: here is the code that I ended up using:   endpoints.MapHealthChecks("healthcheck", new HealthCheckOptions()
    {
     Predicate = _ => true,
     ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
    });